# Hide Toolbar in activity from fragment using CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout

Good Day, I have a `HomeActivity` with `Toolbar` and `ViewPager`. In `ViewPager` there is `Fragment` with `RecyclerView`. I would like to hide `ToolBar` onScrolling `RecyclerView` in `Fragment`. I make this using `CoordinatorLayout`, but it not working. Any ideas ?

`activity_home.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.HomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/mantis"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vpPager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`fragment_home.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 tools:context=".fragments.BusFragment">
    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/busRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

I think I should make behavior to `RecyclerView`, like it is in `ViewPager`

> app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

maybe there is option to make it programatically ? Or my idea isn`t good at all?
Anyway,  thank you!

Comment: why you want to apply it programmatically?

Comment: because I don't have ideas how apply `app:layout_behavior` to `RecyclerView`. It`s not mandatory, it is only my idea

Comment: Not sure, but it can be coming from having AppBarLayout in LinearLayout as parent, instead directly in CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: @VadimL. just add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your `CoordinatorLayout` and `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your `ViewPager`.

Comment: @VipulAsri unfortunately `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` don't help me, and `ViewPager` already has behavior

Comment: BTW why are you using `LinearLayout` as parent of `AppBarLayout`?

Comment: It's because in other way `Toolbar` don't appear at all

Comment: add collapsing toolbar....you havent added that try this http://d-codepages.com/collapsing-toolbar-android-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `LinearLayout` as parent of `AppBarLayout` and move `PagerSlidingTabStrip` inside `AppBarLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/mantis"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vpPager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This example will will work for you.Just copy this in your own project and replace the Tablayout with your PagerslidingTabstrip if you want to use this.

Here ist the acitivitymain.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="lh.com.myapplicationstack.MainActivity"
android:background="#e8e8e8">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|enterAlways"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="#e7e7e7" />


<!-- Put the part below this comment into your Fragment.xml(Wrap it with a Linearlayout) -->
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/Nested_scroll_view"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="#FAFAFA"
    android:padding="4dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Item1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Item2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Item3"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<!-- Put the part above this comment into your Fragment.xml(Wrap it with a Linearlayout)-->


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CoordinatorLayout rootLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initInstances();
}

private void initInstances() {

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    rootLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);


}
}
```

This is the styles.xml which removes the standart Toolbar.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#1565C0</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#0d47a1</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.WithoutActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

This is the manifest where you use the custom style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="lh.com.myapplicationstack" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WithoutActionBar" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Just copy all these files to your project and customize it as you like.